# Listing all (AIO with DIO) operations

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, unix

I wrote a program that does AIO read on a file. It combines a bunch of aiocb structures on a list and passes it on to lio_listio() which takes care of the I/O's. Here I have used LIO_WAIT mode so that all I/O's will be completed. This works fine in case of buffered read (opening file with only O_RDWR).

I tried the same by opening file with O_DIRECT. Here lio_listio() returns -1 with errno set to EIO. I think lio_listio() does not work with DIO.

Is there any function similar to lio_listio() that I can use with DIO and wait for all my requests to be complete.

Comment: Direct IO on Linux generally requires page-size IO operations and only works with page-aligned user-space buffers, but the specifics are very file-system dependent.  Note that POSIX asynchronous IO on Linux [is just a glibc bodge that uses multiple threads calling `pread()` or `pwrite()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html#notes)`: "The current Linux POSIX AIO implementation is provided in user space by glibc.  This has a number of limitations..."  It's no different than normal IO.

Comment: Note from that same link:  "Work has been in progress for some
       time on a kernel state-machine-based implementation of
       asynchronous I/O (see io_submit(2), io_setup(2), io_cancel(2),
       io_destroy(2), io_getevents(2)), but this implementation hasn't
       yet matured to the point where the POSIX AIO implementation can
       be completely reimplemented using the kernel system calls."